# Is there any solution for ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''

Tags: python, tkinter, scikit-learn, valueerror

** Im getting this Value error on
age2 = float(Age1)
gender2 = float(gender1)
this code im not sure why this error is caused and need a solution**

The data of Age1 and gender1 is str but i want it to be in float so i added this code but the Value error shows up idk why

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('400x400')
root.resizable(0,0)
root.title('Data Check')
root.config(bg ='seashell3')
Age = StringVar()
gender = StringVar()

def predicts():

    Age1 = Age.get()
    gender1 = gender.get()

    age2 = int(Age1)
    gender2 = int(gender1)

    music_data = pd.read_csv('music.csv')
    x = music_data.drop(columns=['genre'])
    y = music_data['genre']
    x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size = 0.2)

    model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
    model.fit(x_train,y_train)
    predictions = model.predict(x_test)

    model1 = DecisionTreeClassifier()
    model1.fit(x,y)
    predictions1 = model1.predict([[age2,gender2]])

    score = accuracy_score(y_test, predictions)
    print(score,predictions1)
    Label(root, text = score, font = 'arial 15 bold').place(x = 90, y = 220)
    Label(root, text = predictions1, font = 'arial 15 bold').place(x = 120, y = 220)

predicts()


Label(root, text = 'Enter Age and Gender(0,1)' , font='arial 15 bold', bg = 'seashell2').place(x = 20,y=70)
Entry(root, font = 'arial 15', textvariable = Age , bg = 'antiquewhite2').place(x=90 , y = 130)
Entry(root, font = 'arial 15', textvariable = gender , bg = 'antiquewhite2').place(x=90 , y = 160)
Button(root, font = 'arial 13 bold', text = 'Predict'  ,padx =5,bg ='seashell4' ,command = predicts). place(x = 90, y = 290)

def Exit():
    root.destroy()

Button(root, font = 'arial 13 bold', text = 'EXIT'  ,padx =5,bg ='seashell4' ,command = Exit).place(x=230,y=310)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does int casting work, since it is in the code?

Comment: Try printing `Age1`. What does it give you? Is it in the form of a float?

Comment: Ok, so it is not string to float but StringVar. I am not very familiar with tkinter but I think `StringVar()` must sit in some sort of loop. So my guess is that at some point it receives something else than string and this explicit `float()` casting does not work. As @TheLizzard suggested try printing those values to see what it will return.

Comment: @kaktus_car `StringVar` doesn't have any loops in its implementation (or at least that is why I think). Each time you change the contents of the `Entry` it sets the value of the `StringVar`. It's basically a wrapper for a string that exists in tcl's world.

Comment: Oh, ok, my bad then. Glad you found the issue

Comment: @kaktus_car: _"I think StringVar() must sit in some sort of loop"_ - no, nothing at all like that. Instances of `StringVar` are just normal objects.

Answer (score 2):

I think I found the problem:
in your code you have:

```py
...
Age = StringVar()
...
predicts()
...
Button(..., command=predicts).place(...)
```

The problem is that you call `predicts()` just after you create the `StringVar` so its contents are `""`. And if we do `float("")` we get:

```py
>>> float("")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    float("")
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 
>>>
```

So actually that is what python was telling you :D

If you remove the `predicts()` but keep the `command=predicts`, it should solve your problem.